# warning when calculating predicted values

Tags: r, lm, predict

working with a data frame

```
x
    Date      Val
    1/1/2012   7
    2/1/2012   9
    3/1/2012   20
    4/1/2012   24
    5/1/2012   50
a <- seq(as.Date(tail(x, 1)$Date), by="month", length=5)
a <- data.frame(a)
x.lm <- lm(x$Val ~ x$Date)

x.pre<-predict(x.lm, newdata=a)
```

I am getting this erro:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 5 rows but variable(s) found have 29 rows
```

what am I doing wrong?

here is the dput output:

```
dput(x)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 
14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14975, 
15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 
15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461), class = "Date"), 
    Val = c(45, 51, 56, 56, 59, 60, 60, 60, 64, 65, 75, 73, 74, 
    80, 87, 91, 92, 96, 109, 108, 123, 129, 133, 143, 127, 127, 
    123, 121, 130)), .Names = c("Date", "Val"), row.names = c(NA, 
29L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is the `z` in your first line supposed to be an `x`? otherwise we don't know what `z` is.  You aren't getting an error, you're getting a warning.  Also, nothing you've show us has 29 rows so we cannot repeat this.  Use `dput` to show us your actual data.

Comment: sorry, yest it is x. I just updated it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your variable names, as stored in the `x.lm` model, refer to the `x` dataframe. There are no variables of the same names in `a`, so it will use those 29 from `x` again, which is probably not what you wanted, thus the warning. You can do the following to always use an unqualified variable named `Date` in the model:

```
a <- seq(as.Date(tail(x, 1)$Date), by="month", length=5)
a <- data.frame(Date = a)
x.lm <- lm(Val ~ Date, data=x)
x.pre<-predict(x.lm, newdata=a)
```

Comment: or `x.lm <- lm(Val~Date,data=x); predict(x.lm, newdata=data.frame(Date=a))`

Comment: @BenBolker, you're right, a `with(x,…)` is probably overkill here. Changed my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, is there any way to look at how R parameter passing works that does not hurt your brain?

Comment: @FlorianMayer: Have you read [section 4.3 of the language reference](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Evaluation)?

Answer (score 1):

Your `data.frame a` has a column named `a`.  You created your model with columns named `Val` and `Date` so that is what its looking for.

when you make your `data.frame a` name that column `Date` and you're good to go:

```
a <- data.frame(Date=a)
```

Then it runs without the warning.

Per comment:

Edit your `lm` call to be:

```
lm(Val ~ Date, data=x)
```

Comment: Still gives the warning for me, as the variable is called `x$Date` here. Even actually calling it `"x$Date"` in the data frame dos not appear to be enough. Have you tested this just as the OP wrote it? If so, there might be a difference between your version of R and my 2.15.1.

Comment: @MvG yeah, you're right, I had changed the OP's code while fiddling and forgot.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make `predict.lm()` work, then you should try to write your own function using `function()`:

```
yourown_function<- function(predictor1, predictor2,...){intercept+b1*predictor1+b2*predictor2+...}
```

use `yourown_function` to predict from any new dataframe:

```
newvalues<- yourown_function(predictor1=data.frame$predictor1, predictor2=data.frame$predictor2,....)
```

using the new values, you can compute residuals, MSE, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of x.lm <- lm(x$Val ~ x$Date, data = x) use x.lm <- lm(Val ~ Date, data = x). Removing dataset name before variable name in the lm function  should help.