# predict warning

Tags: r, warnings, predict

i'm getting this warning while trying to predict values for my test data frame.
here is my code to build the tree and predict:

```
library(pgmm)
data(olive)
olive = olive[,-1]
tree2 <- tree(olive$Area ~ olive$Palmitic + olive$Palmitoleic+olive$Stearic+olive$Oleic+olive$Linoleic+olive$Linolenic+olive$Arachidic+olive$Eicosenoic,data=olive)
newdata = as.data.frame(t(colMeans(olive)))
pred1 <- predict(tree2,newdata)
```

i read a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802943/warning-when-calculating-predicted-values) so i replaced this line

```
newdata = as.data.frame(t(colMeans(olive)))
```

by

```
aa<-t(colMeans(olive))
aa[1,1]
newdata <- data.frame(Palmitic=aa[1,1],Palmitoleic=aa[1,2],Stearic=aa[1,3],Oleic=aa[1,4],Linoleic=aa[1,5],Linolenic=aa[1,6],Arachidic=aa[1,7],Eicosenoic=aa[1,8])
```

code to names columns of my dataset but i'm still getting the same warning and prediction is wrong :-/

Comment: try eliminating the `$` from your model: `tree2 <- tree(Area ~ Palmitic + Palmitoleic+Stearic+Oleic+Linoleic+Arachidic+Eicosenoic,data=olive)`

Comment: Could you please clarify your intended result?

Comment: that worked Ben :) thanks. I want to predict the area for an input vector which have the mean of other columns Jack :)

Comment: what package is `tree()` in ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Probably the old (and now little used) precursor to **rpart**, I think. The package is called **tree**.

Answer (score 1):

(Upgraded from a comment.)

Try eliminating the `$` from your model:

```
tree2 <- tree(Area ~ Palmitic + Palmitoleic+Stearic+Oleic+
    Linoleic+Linolenic+Arachidic+Eicosenoic,data=olive)
```

In principle, you can further simplify this to

```
tree(Area~.-Region,data=olive)
```

where `.` specifies "all other variables in the data set", and `-Region` says you *don't* want to include the `Region` variable.  (Oops, this doesn't actually work -- although I think it should)

The basic issue is that `predict` is trying to look within `newdata` for the names of the predictor variables specified in the original model: it needs to be looking for `predvar`, not `origdata$predvar`.

I would use:

```
predict(tree3,newdata=as.data.frame(rbind(colMeans(olive[-(1:2)]))))
```